# Open Background Restriction in settings

Tags: android, background, android-9.0-pie

I need to show a warning to user if **Background Restriction** is applied (`Android 9 and higher`) and ask them to disable it.
What Intent I can use to open "Background Restriction" settings of my app and show it to user?

Note : I am not looking for background data, but background activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Background Activity is enabled or not by calling the following method

```
ActivityManager.isBackgroundRestricted()
```

And You can't open settings of background activity restrictions to ask user to disable it,instead show a popup describing how to disable background activity restrictions(Step by step guide).

The following Intent opens app settings page of our app,where he can disable background restrictions

```
Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null))
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: `@AVEbrahimi` Is that covers your problem?